# How to print message(s) at the end of configure/make?

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure

I'm trying to setup a software package with GNU autotools and would like for a message "Build successful!" to be outputted after a user has run make (after configure). How would I implement such a feature? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clean way of doing it. You can add a printout to the top-level make target:

```
all:
       $(MAKE) ... && echo "Build succeeded"
```

Comment: Hmm.. I was afraid I would have to resort to something like that. I was also hoping that there was a macro I may have overlooked that performs this same functionality, but I guess not. Thanks for your reply!